# Area persistent sidebar MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an area in my web application. This area has several controllers. There is one controller which handles the entry to the area (i.e. everything passes through this controller to access other controllers in the area). This controller requires an ID to be passed to the action:

```
    public ActionResult Index(Guid appID)
    {
        var vm = new DeviceManagementViewModel
        {
            SelectedApp = appID,
            App = _repository.AUTs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID.Equals(appID)),
            Devices = GetDevices()
        };

        return View(vm);
    }
```

The view it creates then posts back with another ID. So now there are two ID's that have been obtained and are persisted throughout the area.

Each Create, Edit and Details action in each Controller needs these two ID's to be passed so that it can show the correct data, e.g.:

```
    public ActionResult Create(Guid appID, Guid deviceID)
    {
        var vm = new InputViewModel
        {
            Device = deviceID,
            Application = appID
        };

        return View(vm);
    }
```

Now it would be great if I could have a sidebar which has quicklinks to each Detail and Create action filled out with the relevant ID's e.g.:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create Input Methods", "Create", "Input", new { appID = <-- ID ONE -->, deviceID = <-- ID TWO --> }, null)
```

And, it would be even greater to persist this sidebar throughout the entire area, so you could quickly switch through each controller. I've read this [blog](http://blog.voltje.be/2012/08/21/creating-a-dynamic-sidebar-with-asp-net-mvc/) I'm wondering how it works, if it is what I'm looking for? If there is actually an even more simple way of doing it.

So a quick recap, I need a sidebar which can be dynamically updated when this specific area has been entered (which can only be entered through one point) which links (using extra parameters to pass the TWO IDs) to their corresponding actions and controllers and also persists through all views in the area.

Thanks,

------ EDIT -------

Alright, to help move this along a bit. I expect that I will have an Action that will pass these 2 ID parameters to:

```
public ActionResult Menu(Guid appID, Guid deviceID)
{
    var vm = MenuViewModel
    {
        DeviceID = deviceID,
        ApplicationID = appID
    };

    return PartialView(vm);
}
```

this will have a ViewModel like so:

```
public class MenuViewModel
{
    public Guid ApplicationID {get; set;}
    public Guid DeviceID {get; set;}
}
```

and a partial view like so:

```
<aside id="dashboard_menu">
<div id="extras">
    <div class="oi">
        <h2 class="screenreader-only">Menu</h2>

        <div class="rollup section">
            <h3 class="rollup-trigger">Input Methods</h3> 
            <p>View or Add more Input Methods</p>
            <p class="more"><a href="#">&raquo; @Html.ActionLink("View", "Index", "Input", new { appID = Model.ApplicationID, deviceID = Model.DeviceID}, null)</a></p>
            <p class="more"><a href="#">&raquo; @Html.ActionLink("Add", "Create", "Input", new { appID = Model.ApplicationID, deviceID = Model.DeviceID}, null)</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="rollup section">
            <h3 class="rollup-trigger">Launch &amp; Exit</h3> 
            <p>View or Add more Launch &amp; Exit</p>
            <p class="more"><a href="#">&raquo; @Html.ActionLink("View", "Index", "Launch", new { appID = Model.ApplicationID, deviceID = Model.DeviceID}, null)</a></p>
            <p class="more"><a href="#">&raquo; @Html.ActionLink("Add", "Create", "Launch", new { appID = Model.ApplicationID, deviceID = Model.DeviceID}, null)</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="rollup section">
            <h3 class="rollup-trigger">Performance</h3> 
            <p>View or Add more Performance</p>
            <p class="more"><a href="#">&raquo; @Html.ActionLink("View", "Index", "Performance", new { appID = Model.ApplicationID, deviceID = Model.DeviceID}, null)</a></p>
            <p class="more"><a href="#">&raquo; @Html.ActionLink("Add", "Create", "Performance", new { appID = Model.ApplicationID, deviceID = Model.DeviceID}, null)</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="rollup section">
            <h3 class="rollup-trigger">Power Consumption</h3> 
            <p>View or Add more Power Consumption</p>
            <p class="more"><a href="#">&raquo; @Html.ActionLink("View", "Index", "Power", new { appID = Model.ApplicationID, deviceID = Model.DeviceID}, null)</a></p>
            <p class="more"><a href="#">&raquo; @Html.ActionLink("Add", "Create", "Power", new { appID = Model.ApplicationID, deviceID = Model.DeviceID}, null)</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="rollup section">
            <h3 class="rollup-trigger">Qualitative Validation</h3> 
            <p>View or Add more Qualitative Validation</p>
            <p class="more"><a href="#">&raquo; @Html.ActionLink("View", "Index", "Qual", new { appID = Model.ApplicationID, deviceID = Model.DeviceID}, null)</a></p>
            <p class="more"><a href="#">&raquo; @Html.ActionLink("Add", "Create", "Qual", new { appID = Model.ApplicationID, deviceID = Model.DeviceID}, null)</a></p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

So now, how do I make this persistent, do I use it in the _Layout.cshtml for the area? if so how?

Do I use it in every view page if so, how can I not do that because it seems like more work than necessary?

All I'm confused about, is how you pass those ID parameters to the partial view and where the partial view gets load up from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer is with help from this [blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx):

This is a per view page answer unfortunately.

Define a section in the layout page:

```
@if (IsSectionDefined("SideBar"))
{
    @RenderSection("SideBar")
}
else
{
    <div id="extras">
        <div class="oi">
            <h2 class="screenreader-only">Menu</h2>

            <div class="rollup section">
                <h3 class="rollup-trigger">Application Validation</h3> 
                <p>Goto all Applications</p>
                <p class="more"><a href="#">&raquo; @Html.ActionLink("All Applications", "Index", "Application", new { area = "Validation" }, null)</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>   
}
```

Then on each page with a view (which i guess if you created this layout page first then the views would automatically put in the sidebar section for you to just fill out) put:

```
@section SideBar {
    @{Html.RenderAction("Menu", "DeviceManagement", new { appID = Model.Application, deviceID = Model.Device })}
}
```

Inside the Menu partial view, will be:

```
<div id="extras">
<div class="oi">
    <h2 class="screenreader-only">Menu</h2>

    <div class="rollup section">
        <h3 class="rollup-trigger">Input Methods</h3> 
        <p>View or Add more Input Methods</p>
        <p class="more"><a href="#">&raquo; @Html.ActionLink("View", "Index", "Input", new { appID = Model.ApplicationID, deviceID = Model.DeviceID}, null)</a></p>
        <p class="more"><a href="#">&raquo; @Html.ActionLink("Add", "Create", "Input", new { appID = Model.ApplicationID, deviceID = Model.DeviceID}, null)</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="rollup section">
        <h3 class="rollup-trigger">Launch &amp; Exit</h3> 
        <p>View or Add more Launch &amp; Exit</p>
        <p class="more"><a href="#">&raquo; @Html.ActionLink("View", "Index", "Launch", new { appID = Model.ApplicationID, deviceID = Model.DeviceID}, null)</a></p>
        <p class="more"><a href="#">&raquo; @Html.ActionLink("Add", "Create", "Launch", new { appID = Model.ApplicationID, deviceID = Model.DeviceID}, null)</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="rollup section">
        <h3 class="rollup-trigger">Performance</h3> 
        <p>View or Add more Performance</p>
        <p class="more"><a href="#">&raquo; @Html.ActionLink("View", "Index", "Performance", new { appID = Model.ApplicationID, deviceID = Model.DeviceID}, null)</a></p>
        <p class="more"><a href="#">&raquo; @Html.ActionLink("Add", "Create", "Performance", new { appID = Model.ApplicationID, deviceID = Model.DeviceID}, null)</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="rollup section">
        <h3 class="rollup-trigger">Power Consumption</h3> 
        <p>View or Add more Power Consumption</p>
        <p class="more"><a href="#">&raquo; @Html.ActionLink("View", "Index", "Power", new { appID = Model.ApplicationID, deviceID = Model.DeviceID}, null)</a></p>
        <p class="more"><a href="#">&raquo; @Html.ActionLink("Add", "Create", "Power", new { appID = Model.ApplicationID, deviceID = Model.DeviceID}, null)</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="rollup section">
        <h3 class="rollup-trigger">Qualitative Validation</h3> 
        <p>View or Add more Qualitative Validation</p>
        <p class="more"><a href="#">&raquo; @Html.ActionLink("View", "Index", "Qual", new { appID = Model.ApplicationID, deviceID = Model.DeviceID}, null)</a></p>
        <p class="more"><a href="#">&raquo; @Html.ActionLink("Add", "Create", "Qual", new { appID = Model.ApplicationID, deviceID = Model.DeviceID}, null)</a></p>
    </div>

</div>
```

and the menu action will look like the one in the question.

Done. It's more Elegant than I anticipated after no answers were left. But is what I require.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is fantastic if you need to be able to specify different sidebar actions for each View; however, if you want area-specific sidebars, this adds unnecessary overhead and duplication in each View, which could make your solution difficult to manage if anything changes.

To avoid this, you could try creating a `BaseController` for each Area, which specifies the sidebar Action. You can then determine the current area in the View and use this to call the correct Action with `RenderAction`

```
public class SomeAreaBaseController : Controller
{
    public SomeAreaBaseController()
    {
        ViewBag.HasSidebar = true;
        ViewBag.Application = ...;
        ViewBag.Device = ...;
    }
    public ActionResult Menu(Guid appID, Guid deviceID)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now, inherit from this in your other controllers for this area:

```
public class SomeController : SomeAreaBaseController
```

And then, in `Layout.cshtml`...

```
@if (ViewBag.HasSidebar) {
    @Html.RenderAction("Menu", ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"], 
        new { appID = ViewBag.Application, deviceID = ViewBag.Device })
}
```

Comment: where would the Model come from? the layout doesn't have the Model of the MenuViewModel which is returned from the Menu Action

Comment: Good question. Something I overlooked, but personally I'd say that, for parameters this simple, it'd be best just to add them to the ViewBag on each request using whatever method you would normally use and retrieve them from there in the View. If your Action started needing a more complex model, you could create this model explicitly in the `BaseController` and pass `ViewBag.SomeModel` to `RenderAction`. See my edit. Either that, or encapsulate the Application/Device detection within the sidebar action and pass no arguments.

Comment: I think its a very good answer and something I definately use in the future, however for my problem I think it may be less complicated doing the way I've done it, if the sidebar changes in my way it is persisted through all the views, same with the default sidebar which I re-factored into its on action and partial view

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; if your "Menu" action changes in your solution, you have to change it for every controller in the area. With this solution, you simply change it in the base controller. Similarly, doing it your way means duplicating markup in each view, when really this markup belongs somewhere shared (unless you plan to render different sidebars on different pages within the same area).

Comment: No, the Menu is in one controller, that is it. This is then pulled using Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Mangement", new { appID...... etc. As for the sidebar, I simply put in the layout section Sidebar etc etc in the view I use Sidebar { render action code }

Comment: That makes sense and will work well for a smaller number of views. I think my confusion comes from the fact that you seemed to want Area-specific menus, rather than View-specific ones. Either way will work, it just depends on how scalable a solution you need.